# "Tease" or "tease with"

Tags: word-usage

Does this [headline](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/gigabyte-x99-ud4-tease,27501.html#xtor=RSS-181) from Toms Hardware use a correct sense of the verb "tease" (the main sense of which in this area being *to tantalize especially by arousing desire or curiosity often without intending to satisfy it*):

> Gigabyte Teases LED-Lit X99-UD4 Motherboard

I thought it should have been "teases with", because in this form it is not clear whether the brand teased the product, or teased people with the product. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like weird use, indeed. It reminds me of "share me your screen" that came up earlier today.

Comment: You need to add an attribution if your definition is a quote.

Comment: WhyCry's answer (now deleted) mentioned the growing use of this usage of 'tease' (a product, idea, plan ...); while it is not given in any dictionary I've checked in, there do seem to be more and more examples on the internet ('the company has teased the entry level luxury sedan'; 'NASA teased the possibility of building a lunar settlement'...) It's probably in the 'some find it acceptable, some find it not' category.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tease) has `tease` listed as a verb used with an object that means to show something in a way designed to attract attention and interest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly new usage of *tease*, but I've seen it all too often in recent years at the online tech publishing sites where I've worked.

Essentially the word "Teases" in the headline "Gigabyte Teases LED-Lit X99-UD4 Motherboard" means "promotes in a teasing fashion." Why "a teasing fashion"? Because the product isn't ready for actual previewing yet, so the point is to drum up interest and free publicity (in the form of avid speculation) at what might be called Geek Rumor sites, long before there is any there there.

I don't know where the usage originated, but tech journalists are especially susceptible to this type of marketing department invitation to wax enthusiastic over a prospective product, perhaps because the hunger for new stuff in that field is insatiable. In any event, my guess is that tech journalists initially used "teasing" internally (that is, to other writers and editors at their publication and elsewhere in the industry) to refer to brief mentions or artist renderings of pre-prototype devices offered by the people at the lectern at manufacturers' or vendors' press events—and from there, the usage leaked into news reports about such events.

To demonstrate that no recently emerged usage is so new that it can't be worked to death, here are 29 "teases" headlines that a Google search finds on a site-specific search of a single tech website—[PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com)—in the past six years:

> "[LG Teases Latest 'Black Label' Cell Phone Ahead of Launch](http://www.pcworld.com/article/144227/article.html)" [April 7, 2008]
>
> "[Apple Teases Black Friday 'shopping Event'](http://www.pcworld.com/article/154503/article.html)" [November 25, 2008]
>
> "[Stream This: AMD Teases Cloud Computing Game Revolution](http://www.pcworld.com/article/156820/amd_cloud_gaming.html)" [January 9, 2009]
>
> "[Sega Teases Total War: Napoleon for Windows](http://www.pcworld.com/article/170443/napoleon_total_war.html)" [August 19, 2009]
>
> "[Rare Teases Perfect Dark Xbox Live High-Def Shots](http://www.pcworld.com/article/170660/perfect_dark_xbla.html)" [August 24, 2009]
>
> "[LucasArts Teases Star Wars The Force Unleashed 2](http://www.pcworld.com/article/184662/star_wars_force_unleashed_2.html)" [December 15, 2009]
>
> "[Nvidia Teases Fermi GF100 Showing at CES 2010](http://www.pcworld.com/article/185774/nvidia_fermi_ces_2010.html)" [January 4, 2010]
>
> "[Halo: Reach Live-Action Trailer Teases Spartan Birth](http://www.pcworld.com/article/195152/halo_reach_live_action_trailer.html)" [April 28, 2010]
>
> "[Valve quietly teases a Left 4 Dead release date for Mac](http://www.macworld.com/article/1154095/left_4_dead_mac.html)" [September 15, 2010]
>
> "[Apple teases Black Friday shopping event](http://www.macworld.com/article/1155917/apple_black_friday_2010.html)" [November 23, 2010]
>
> "[World of Warcraft Cataclysm Trailer Teases New Areas](http://www.pcworld.com/article/212397/world_of_warcraft_cataclysm_trailer_teases_new_areas.html)" [December 3, 2010]
>
> "[Mozilla Teases Windows 8 Metro Firefox with Screenshots](http://www.pcworld.com/article/253086/mozilla_teases_windows_8_metro_firefox_with_screenshots.html)" [April 3, 2012]
>
> "[Google's 'Project Glasses' Teases Augmented Reality Glasses](http://www.pcworld.com/article/253200/googles_project_glass_teases_augmented_reality_glasses.html)" [April 4, 2012]
>
> "[Samsung Teases Windows 8 Tablet Hybrid Launch at IFA 2012](http://www.pcworld.com/article/261479/samsung_teases_windows_8_tablet_hybrid_launch_at_ifa_2012.html)" [August 27, 2012]
>
> "[Sony teases an OLED 4K set at CES 2013](http://www.techhive.com/article/2024195/sony-teases-an-oled-4k-set-at-ces-2013.html)" [January 7, 2013]
>
> "[Apple teases 'new product categories'](http://www.techhive.com/article/2036254/apple-teases-new-product-categories.html)" [April 23, 2013]
>
> "[Nokia teases Lumia 928 but stays mum on launch date](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9238965/Nokia_teases_Lumia_928_but_still_mum_on_launch_date)" [May 7, 2013]
>
> "[Major Nelson teases E3 for Xbox One news](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2039561/major-nelson-teases-e3-for-xbox-one-news.html)" [May 22, 2013]
>
> "[Sony teases Yoga-like Windows 8 convertible in advance of IFA trade show](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2047135/sony-teases-yoga-like-windows-8-convertible-in-advance-of-ifa-trade-show.html)" [August 21, 2013]
>
> "[Microsoft's Surface boss teases more than just 10-inch tablets](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2050763/microsofts-surface-boss-teases-more-than-just-10-inch-tablets.html)" [October 1, 2013]
>
> "[Myst creator Rand Miller teases new Kickstarter project during IndieCade](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2052187/myst-creator-rand-miller-teases-new-kickstarter-project-during-indiecade.html)" [October 6, 2013]
>
> "[Digital Storm teases its new Steam Machine](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2079344/digital-storm-teases-its-new-steam-machine.html)" [December 11, 2013]
>
> "[ZTE teases 6-inch Android device and Firefox OS smartphone](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2098680/zte-teases-6-inch-android-device-and-firefox-os-smartphone.html)" [February 18, 2014]
>
> "[Samsung teases Galaxy S5 in adjective-filled video](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2099981/galaxy-s5-teaser.html)" [February 21, 2014]
>
> "[Microsoft reveals next-gen Kinect for Windows design, teases launch](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2137460/microsoft-reveals-next-gen-kinect-for-windows-design-teases-launch.html)" [March 28, 2014]
>
> "[Surface Mini inbound? Microsoft teases 'small' Surface event on May 20](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2151462/surface-mini-inbound-microsoft-teases-small-gathering-on-may-20.html)" [May 6, 2014]
>
> "[Asus teases a host of PC-gaming products, including a potential Steam Machine](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2358482/asus-teases-a-host-of-pc-gaming-products-including-a-potential-steam-machine.html)" [June 2, 2014]
>
> "[Amazon teases launch of mysterious device with 50-second video](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2359960/amazon-teases-launch-of-mysterious-device-with-50second-video.html)" [June 4, 2014]
>
> "[Microsoft teases Lumia smartphone announcements for September 4](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2463962/microsoft-teases-lumia-smartphone-announcements-for-september-4.html)" [August 12, 2014]

Sick of it yet?